# HTML How to display with div?

Tags: css

Is there a way to have either `<div>`, and when the text is inside, it gets formatted exactly like how it is?

Comment: You can use css Flexbox to do that. https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties Alternatively you can use HTML Table http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: @Jessica Sorry but could you show an example with what I provided for clarification? So I can accept the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with div and white-space pre-wrap. You might have forgotten to set `font-family:monospace;` to preserve letter spacing.

```css
div.pre{
  white-space:pre-wrap;
  font-family:monospace;
  }
```

```html
<div class="pre">
                 Convention 21423 ABC
    ROOM        NAME      PPL   ATTEND       OUT      
   2252857  YELLOW_ROOM   589     30%        50%  
</div>
```

Comment: I gave it a try but it just put everything in one line. I took a screenshot of it and put it in the original post. Please take a look before I accept the answer. Thank you in advance

Comment: you can see that the code snippet in my answer yields the correct result. if you are getting something different than it may be due to something else in your environment that I have no way of knowing about